# Max frame payload length in WebFlux WebSockets

Tags: java, websocket, spring-webflux, netty

I'm using Sping WebFlux websockets. I'm sending byte data, everything works for small files below 64kb, but bigger ones brakes with  "Connection closed by WebSocket server (code=0, reason=)".

No matter how I configure my WebSocketHandler I can send big message via Web Sockets.

I'm setting in my configuration class:

```
    @Bean
    public WebSocketService webSocketService() {
        return new HandshakeWebSocketService(
                new ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(WebsocketServerSpec.builder()
                        .maxFramePayloadLength(1024 * 1024 * 10)));
    }
```

No matter what i put in *maxFramePayloadLength* i see no change (well maxFramePayloadLength <= 0 works and throw an error, so bean is read).